# Error in asp:Chart control

Tags: c#-4.0, mschart

I am using a Chart control in my website. the code and chart control is working perfectly on my local machine. But when i am deploying it on web server its giving error. I have also change version of my site to 4.0 and given all the tab and references in web.config

The Error is

System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Invalid temp directory in chart handler configuration [c:\TempImageFiles]. at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandlerSettings.Inspect() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandlerSettings.ParseParams(String parameters) at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.InitializeParameters() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.get_Settings() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.InitializeControllerFile() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler.EnsureInitialized(Boolean hardCheck) at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.GetImageStorageMode() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.get_CurrentImageLocation() at System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlContainerControl.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildrenInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ICollection children) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderChildren(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Page.Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest() at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context) at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) at ASP.reports_rptresultchart_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) in c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\466f50e4\198c9161\App_Web_jolxexts.2.cs:line 0 at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Here, I cannot find exactly why the directory error is giving for directory c:\TempImageFiles as i havent used anywhere in my entire code for this path.

Please can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following entry to the appsettings section of your web config.

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;" />
```

If there is already an entry there then replace it with this one.

EDIT

Instead you could supply a path to your folder

```
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=PathToYourDirectory;"/>
```

Alternatively there is [an article here](https://web.archive.org/web/20201205231110/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081909-1.aspx) that should give you lots of things to try.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the early response. but now its giving error for the temp directory in my root folder for unauthorized access. I have created a temp directory in my httpdocs but the problem persists...